# The relationship between UIViewController and UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm trying to understand how these two are connected. Every time you make a UIViewController does it also automatically come with its own UIView?

Also are these from Cocoa or Objective-C?

Comment: Neither: Those classes are from Cocoa Touch. Cocoa does not have UIKit, so it does not have those classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIViewController is a Cocoa Touch class built for the purpose of managing UIViews.  It expects to have a view hierarchy, but you don't "automatically" get a view (*this is slightly inaccurate; see edit below*).  Usually you will obtain views by calling initWithNibName on your view controller.

There is some built-in magic in Interface Builder which knows that if File's Owner is a UIViewController (or subclass), there is a property called view. That's about it.

Once you have linked a view controller and a view, the view controller does a fair amount of work for you: it registers as a responder for view touch events, registers for device rotation notifications (and handles them automatically, if you wish), helps you take care of some of the details of animation, and handles low-memory conditions semi-automatically.

**Edit**: correction—if you don't call initWithNibName or set the view property manually, the view property getter will invoke loadView if view is nil. The default implementation of loadView will see if you've set nibBundle and nibName and attempt to load the view from there (which is why you don't *have* to call initWithNibName, most of the time), but if those properties aren't set, it will instantiate a UIView object with default values.  So technically, yes, it does automatically come with its own UIView, but most of the time that's of little value.

Comment: When you say its supposed to manage views, that is UIView, correct, or are there other kinds of views it manages?

Comment: Yes, UIView and UIView subclasses. As well as whatever other data is necessary to populate those views properly—for example, you might have a NSFetchedResultsController in your UIViewController to populate your UITableView...

Comment: No, UIViewController is a Cocoa Touch class. Cocoa does not have UIKit, so it does not have UIViewController.

Answer (score 4):

UIViewController doesn't automatically come with a view. You have to make a view in the `-loadView` method. By default, this loads the view from the nib file you've specified. You can also override this method to make a custom view if you prefer not to use a nib.

Also, the view is not created right when the UIViewController is created. UIViewController uses a technique known as [lazy-loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) to defer the creation of a view until the view is actually accessed for the first time.